# Escaping html in soap

Tags: html

I am new to using soap. I have a soap method returning an object. one of the attribute is  description. The value of the description is 
"sample description" wrapped around p tag and bold tag respwctively . The soap method returns the description as said above but in soap ui the open tag is displayed as & lt;(without space)
The soap UI version i use is 3.6.1. I could not understand what makes this to happen. I tried applying a function to the description attribute which removes the tags and returns only "sample description" that works fine.The function uses regular expression to remove the tags 
"\<.*?\>".So I confirmed that the tags are readable while this function is getting executed and getting removed by the function, but in soapUI it displays open tag as  & lt; (without space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&lt;` is the HTML encoded version of `<`. It will have to encode `<` tags in the SOAP or else how would it know where the correct SOAP `<` tags are. you need to decode these on the other side, depending on what your connecting to the SOAP service with.